# Can I be referred to the MDN documentation for, what I think are called, blocks?

Tags: javascript

```js
{
let num = 5;
}
```

Do the curly brackets make the above a 'block'? Can anyone pass on any MDN documentation of blocks? I couldn't find it myself.

Comment: Quick google search should have found it, along with numerous other resources that explain them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Answer (score 0):

As [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) already posted in a comment, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) is the link.  Declaring a variable in a block like you did looks strange, but it's useful in `switch` statements to enforce a more intuitive scoping.

For example:

```js
switch (food) {
  case 'apple': {
    const result = 'Yum!';
    socket.send(result);
    break;
  }
  case 'dirt': {
    const result = 'Ew!';
    socket.send(result);
    break;
  }
}
```

Without using blocks for each `case`, you'd get an error about `result` being declared twice.